# How can I create a new number display format

Tags: google-sheets-api

How can I add a new number format category.  I want a number to be displayed in feet and inches.  For example, I want the number 120 to display as 10'-0" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will need a formula to convert 120 (as per given example) into feet and inches.

Then, With Google Sheets API, cells can be modified in place. As mentioned in [Change contents of a cell](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data#change_contents_of_a_cell),

> The cells feed allows for setting a formula on a cell by starting the cell `inputValue` with an = character. The calculated value of the cell is provided as the cell's actual value.

To modify a cell in a worksheet, start by creating an entry element containing the relevant data, which in this case is a formula.

However, please note that it was also mentioned that:

> The cells feed allows formulas to be set on cells. However, the API always returns cell addresses for formulas on cells in R1C1 notation, even if the formula was set with A1 notation.

Complete documentation for this can be found in [Work with cell-based feeds](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data#work_with_cell-based_feeds).

In addition to that, to display it in available number representations , [Number format patterns](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/formats#number_format_patterns) will be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks for getting back but this is not a "number format category" that I'm thinking of.  Using a formula to divide the number and create a number format pattern I understand.

Comment: I want to add a complete new format category - like date or currency or duration.  And allow me to add to the number format patterns for the new "number format category"  I want to have my routine called to format the display of the final value of a cell.